# Find same data in two DataFrames of different shapes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas DataFrames that I would like to compare. For example

```
    a    b    c
A   na   na  na
B   na   1    1
C   na   1    na
```

and

```
    a    b    c
A   1    na   1
B   na   na   na
C   na   1    na
D   na   1    na
```

I want to find the index-column coordinates for any values that are shared, in this case

```
    b
C   1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the `keys` parameter to `concat`, the columns of the resulting dataframe will be comprised of a multi-index which keeps track of the original dataframes:

```
In [1]: c=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1,keys=['df1','df2'])
        c

Out[1]:
   df1           df2
     a    b    c   a   b   c
A   na   na   na   1  na   1
B   na    1    1  na  na  na
C   na    1   na  na   1  na
D  NaN  NaN  NaN  na   1  na
```

Since the underlying arrays now have the same shape, you can now use `==` to broadcast your comparison and use this as a mask to return all matching values:

```
In [171]: m=c.df1[c.df1==c.df2];m
Out[171]:
    a   b   c
A NaN NaN NaN
B NaN NaN NaN
C NaN   1 NaN
D NaN NaN NaN
```

If your 'na' value are actually zeros, you could use a sparse matrix to reduce this to the coordinates of the matching values (you'll lose your index and column names though):

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
print(sp.coo_matrix(m.where(m.notnull(),0)))
  (2, 1)    1.0
```

Comment: Very nice answer, but I think you need `any` instead of `all` there. Also, the OP will still need to find the column that matches.

Comment: Great answer <padding>

Comment: @lev you're right, I misunderstood the his question, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the indices that are different, you can do: `different_indices = [(i,j) for i in range(len((df1 != df2).columns)) for j in range(len(df1 != df2)) if (df1 != df2)[i][j]]`

Or, slightly more readable:

```
m = (df1 != df2)
different_indices = [(i,j) for i in range(len(m.columns)) for j in range(len(m)) if m[i][j]]
```